# String 2 consecutive words with 2 z's in them

Tags: r, regex

I need to do the following task: String that has 2 consecutive words with 2 z's each in them. Assume the words are made up of letters (lowercase and uppercase both ok) and are separated by 1 space. No other characters allowed. Grep is the only command allowed.

I did this:

```
text2 = c("zip dog"," szszzz dsdfaarzdzzz","zip dog carz","Zzip zzck") 

G= grep("([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)( ){1}([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)",text2,fixed=FALSE)
```

But it's reading 2 and 4. I don't know why :( Any thoughts or help?

Comment: SO what is wrong if your regex is reading 2 and 4, thats what you want right ?

Comment: Note that this `[^zZ]*` would match a space..

Answer (score 0):

Or actually you want to "display" the text of output?

```
library(stringr)
text2 = c("zip dog"," szszzz dsdfaarzdzzz","zip dog carz","Zzip zzck") 
G= str_trim(grep("([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)( ){1}([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)([zZ])([^zZ]*)",text2,fixed=FALSE, value=TRUE))
G
# [1] "szszzz dsdfaarzdzzz" "Zzip zzck"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
 # (?i)(?:^|[ ])[a-z]*z[a-z]*z[a-z]*[ ][a-z]*z[a-z]*z[a-z]*(?:$|[ ])

 (?i)
 (?: ^ | [ ] )
 [a-z]* z
 [a-z]* z 
 [a-z]* 
 [ ]  
 [a-z]* z
 [a-z]* z 
 [a-z]* 
 (?: $ | [ ] )
```

Or,  with a capture buffer

```
 # (?i)(?:^|[ ])([a-z]*z[a-z]*z[a-z]*[ ][a-z]*z[a-z]*z[a-z]*)(?=$|[ ])

 (?i)
 (?: ^ | [ ] )
 (
      [a-z]* z
      [a-z]* z 
      [a-z]* 
      [ ]  
      [a-z]* z
      [a-z]* z 
      [a-z]* 
 )
 (?= $ | [ ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
(\w*?)(?i-msnx:zz)(\w*?)( )(\w*?)(?i-msnx:zz)(\w*?)
```

Comment: What is the `zz` for ?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter regex for this task is:

```
(?i)\\w*zz\\w*\\s\\w*zz
```

- Find the indices of the matching strings

  ```
  grep("(?i)\\w*zz\\w*\\s\\w*zz", text2)
  # [1] 2 4
  ```
- The complete string including the matches

  ```
  grep("(?i)\\w*zz\\w*\\s\\w*zz", text2, value = TRUE)
  # [1] " szszzz dsdfaarzdzzz" "Zzip zzck"
  ```